# Question about C fopen function

Tags: c

While I was reading the reference about fopen function, I found out that FOPEN_MAX is a value that the "minimum number of streams that the implementation guarantees can be open simultaneously".

Why it is the minimum number of streams? Doesn't it have to be "the maximum number of streams...." ?

Comment: @Lee: What was the reference - is it a standard ANSI reference?

Comment: This confusion reminded me of the term "Least upper bound". :-)

Comment: It's a minimum on the C library implementation, not a minimum on your program's actions.

Comment: @tommieb : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_179.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minimum number of streams that can be opened = guarantee that at least so many can be opened

Maximum number of streams that can be opened = guarantee that opening any more will certainly fail

What the wording means that if you have less than FOPEN_MAX streams open, it is guaranteed that at least one more can be opened, and the system does not necessarily provide any hard maximum

Comment: Thx for the answer. It seems like I need to learn English more :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds counterintuitive that something "MAX" is the *minimum* number that can be opened simultaneously. But if you're writing portable code, that number is the effective *maximum* that you can use safely.

Consider this code:

```
if (num_open >= FOPEN_MIN) {
    // close some old ones
}
```

Looks odd, right? So calling it `FOPEN_MAX` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Poor wording in my opinion. It would be better to just say that the implementation guarantees that at least FOPEN_MAX streams may be open simultaneously. Note that if you try to open more streams, you may succeed, but it is not guaranteed in advance.

Answer (score 0):

on linux you can adjust the maximum number of allowed open file handles.
See the command ulimit for more information:

For example on my box running as my user right now any process would have a max number of 256 file handles opened at any given time.

```
$ ulimit -n
256
```

see the man page for ulimit for more information( here is a web version): http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

However, I imagine you can't lower it below  FOPEN_MAX

Comment: This is the value for open but not for fopen. The maximum/minimum number of fopen handles can be differnt, thats why a runtime developer for a different language (like a script language) should implement it with native open/read/write calls. Solaris has 256 as a implementation hardware limit, and this is sometimes a problem because on todays machine it is extremely small.